# nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)

Tags: bash, docker, nginx, permissions, dockerfile

I am currently running into a problem trying to set up a new user rather than using root in my docker file.  The image builds fine, however  when I run the container I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] mkdir() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

Below is my dockerfile. I am using redhat UBi image build my dockerfile :

```
USER root
RUN microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y nginx procps shadow-utils net-tools ca-certificates dirmngr gnupg wget vim\
            && microdnf clean all \
            && rpm -q procps-ng

ENV NGINX_USER="api-gatway" \
    NGINXR_UID="8987" \
    NGINX_GROUP="api-gatway" \
    NGINX_GID="8987"     

RUN set -ex; \
  groupadd -r --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_GROUP"; \
  useradd -r --uid "$NGINXR_UID" --gid "$NGINX_GID" "$NGINX_USER" 


COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf


#To start up NGINX 
EXPOSE 80
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/nginx/

RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/tmp/


RUN chmod 755  api-gatway:api-gatway /var/lib/nginx/
RUN chmod 755  api-gatway:api-gatway /var/log/nginx/

EXPOSE 80
USER api-gatway
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Any ideas why this is still not working?

Comment: does it actually manage to build? the `chmod` seems to be mixed up with `chown`. Moreover why don't you use the nginx image?

Comment: sorry i took out the chown command and replaced it with chmod, the image does build up but running it gives me the above erorrs. have to use redhat image due to work requirements

Comment: chmod +x /var/lib/nginx -R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different issues in this image:

- `chmod` is used incorrectly
- no `chown` is present
- you plan to use a [privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html) (80) with a non-root user

IMO this Dockerfile portion should fix part of your troubles:

```sh
RUN mkdir -p /var/lib/nginx/tmp /var/log/nginx \
    && chown -R api-gatway:api-gatway /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx \
    && chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx /var/log/nginx

EXPOSE 1080
USER api-gatway
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Remember to change the port in the nginx configuration as well.

Last but not least, I think you're trying to map the a folder to `/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body` since I don't see any content being copied in the image. In this case, you have to make sure that the folder on the host can be read by the user in the docker container.

Personal opinion: you're better off with the official `nginx` docker image.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, that has fixed this part of my troubles :). using the redhat image due to work requirements

Comment: That does not help in case of that error. I'm wondering how it could help him. I'm very wondered why I get the same error message even if the folder `/var/lib/nginx/tmp` has the permissions 775 and is owned by the user and group running nginx. Even mkdir with that user fails.

Comment: are you sure the user can traverse the folders and reach `/var/lib/nginx/tmp`?